# Get cell value by row and column number using google script

Tags: javascript, cell, google-sheets-api

I have created a function that returns the row indexes which contain the information I am interested in, as below:

```
[0.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 17.0, 18.0, 19.0, 20.0, 21.0, 22.0]
```

I know want to store cell values from certain columns (say Column P row 2) in a list but I cant work out how to use the array above to get values from a cell.

My current code is:

```
for (var y = 0; y < ListOfContact.length; y++) {
   if(ListOfContact[y] == "Wait"){
      ListOfRowNumbers.push(y);
   }
}

Logger.log(ListOfRowNumbers);

var listOfRelevantCells = [];

for (var yy = 0; yy < ListOfRowNumbers.length; yy++) {
//need to push the cell values to listOfRelevantCells

}
```

I simply can't find the function to do this but I am sure it is obvious!

Answer (score 4):

Try using [**`setValue(value)`**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluevalue):

> Sets the value of the range. The value can be numeric, string, boolean or date. If it begins with '=' it is interpreted as a formula.

```
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

 var cell = sheet.getRange("B2");
 cell.setValue(100);
```

You can use [**`getRange(row, column)`**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer)), [**`getRange(row, column, numRows)`**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer)) or [**`getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer))
to enter your cellIndexes.

Hope this helps.